# Replace string in filename with corresponding new name in table

Tags: linux, bash

I currently have hundreds of files in a directory named: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMATCH1xxxxxxxxxx.txt , xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMATCH2xxxxxxxxxx.txt
and a tab delimited table (codes.txt):

NEWNAME1 MATCH1 
 NEWNAME2 MATCH2 
 ect.

Each MATCH is present in five files. For all the files in the directory, I am trying to replace the MATCH in the filename with NEWNAME. The code I have looks like this:

```
for var in $(cat codes.txt)
    do
        from=$(echo $var | cut -f 2)
        to=$(echo $var | cut -f 1)
        rename $from $to *
    done
```

The variables save properly, however the rename command does not rename the files. The rename command works as expected outside the loop. I do not have access to perl rename

Comment: With that construction, `var` will only ever be one word, so `from` will always be the empty string.  You want `while read to from; do ... done < codes.txt`

Comment: @WilliamPursell When I echo my variables they are correct. When I run your while loop, from is an empty string. Any suggestions?

Comment: WilliamPursell's suggested `while/read` loop works for me; could you update the question with the output from `head -2 codes.txt | od -c`; if you could also provide the exact `while/read` code you're running that may help

Comment: The code you've provided does not set `to` and `from` correctly; how did you determine  *'The variables save properly'*?

Comment: You will have to nest your loops. You can read `while read -r to from; do .. done < codes.txt` and within that loop you will need something like `for name in *.txt; do [[ $name =~ $from ]] && mv "$name" "${name/from/to}"; done` Using the proper *Parameter Expansion* avoids spawning a subshell for every call to `cut` and will be much more efficient. You can also read your `codes.txt` file into an associative array and then loop with it as well.

Comment: Do have have any any instances where old (or new) names are substrings of each other, eg, `MATCH1` and `MATCH10`, `NEWMATCH1` and `NEWMATCH10`?

Comment: Also, `for var in $(cat codes.txt)` is a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of* `cat`). Feed a while loop with `codes.txt` and avoid the subshell needed by `cat` and the command substitution. Unless you are concatenating two files or dumping a file to `stdout`, any other use of `cat` is likely a UUOc.

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks for the comment. My current code is: `while read to from;
 do echo $to
       echo $from
       rename $from $to *
 done < sub_barcodes.txt`                                    the echo is returning the expected strings, however the rename does nothing. The names are not substrings of each other

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the info on UUOc, I have rewritten with while loop. I will reply back if your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: Your loop breaks the content of codes.txt into words separated by white space. This means that if either MATCH or NEWNAME is a file name with an embedded space, this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use `awk` to generate the rename commands based on the contents of your `codes` file.  This output could then be piped to `sh` and executed.  Something like:

```
awk '{printf "for i in *%s* ; do mv $i ${i/%s/%s} ; done \n", $2, $2, $1}' codes | sh
```

The generated commands would using bash globbing to locate files by the 'MATCH' strings and would look like:

```
for i in *MATCH1* ; do mv $i ${i/MATCH1/NEWNAME1} ; done 
for i in *MATCH2* ; do mv $i ${i/MATCH2/NEWNAME2} ; done
```

(Note: I am not sure if the `awk` output piped to `sh` would be terribly efficient since you are dealing with hundreds of files.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{system("rename " $2 " " $1 " *" )}' codes.txt
```

Comment: I attempted this solution; the file names did not change. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNEWNAME1xxxxxxxxxx.txt
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNEWNAME2xxxxxxxxxx.txt` this is the result I got, which I think is what you expect

Comment: perhaps `codes.txt` is wrong, did you copy from windows?

Comment: Your solution runs when I set up the reproducible example, but does not work on my real data. An example of a real file whose name I am trying to change is ` nR219-L3-G2-P156-TCGACGTC-TCGCATAA-SampleBasicInfo.txt`, with the MATCH being **TCGACGTC-TCGCATAA** to be changed to NEWNAME **CM3_12H**.  The codes.txt table data is from widows then manipulated on the command line.

Comment: May also depend on whether the `rename` he has installed is from `util-linux` or `perl-rename`. That's what makes `rename` answers tricky. What does `rename --version` show?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin rename --version shows: `util-linux 2.23.2`

Comment: The individual file rename should work then, I haven't tried the rename given the wildcard. May want to change `" *"` to `" *" $2 "*"` so the replacement is directed at only files matching `*$2*` effectively. Though `rename` should be able to pick the proper file out of the list.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The issue was that codes.txt contained a carriage return that I was not noticing.  Works perfectly. Thanks!